# React component not rendered when sub path is called directly

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am having a Server Side Rendered React app where I use HashRouter for react routing(v5). My Routes look like this

```
<HashRouter basename="/">
   <Layout {...config} />
</HashRouter>
```

```
<Switch>
  <Route exact={true} path="/" component={LPComp} />
  <Route exact={true} path={this.props.siteBanner.Red} component={bannerPage} />
</Switch>
```

When I hit `localhost:8888/parent/` and once it get loaded and if I hit `localhost:8888/parent/banner` in the same window the bannerPage component renders  fine.
But I hit `localhost:8888/parent/banner` directly(consider in a new tab), then the component is not rendered properly.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Also to add on when I hit `localhost:8888/parent/banner` I can see LPComp(default route) also being loaded and then it disappears suddenly and the bannerPage component renders improperly.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: this might not be enough to answer you, but to get a rough idea i can say, you must make all routes independent , what i mean by independent is no route should depend on data from any route, be it parent route, which makes it load improperly because of missing data to  load or render your html or some functions may fail and so on...

Comment: Okay.That could be an issue, but any idea why default route is appearing and disappearing for a second before the bannerPage component loads when I hit the /parent/bannerPage

Comment: are you having any routes configured in banner page like if some data is missing go to home page or something like that... a rough guess but have to see

Comment: @pavankumar No there no further routes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is making sense, since your routes is based on a prop/state `this.props.siteBanner.Red`. So the first thing is to put a `console.log` once you enter this component.

```
  console.log(this.props.siteBanner.Red)
```

In your first case, you reach this component from its parent, this way the props mostly likely is resolved.

In your second case, you reach it directly, of course also from its parent, but most likely there's no time for the props to get resolved quickly. Couple of possibilities

- useEffect is to update this variable
- mouse click is required to get a value
- setTimeout is used to defer
- callback is used to get this variable

You can say there's 50ms delay in getting this prop resolved, but you need to dig out why yourself. Dynamic route is more advanced thing, it's easy to have permanent route.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your timely response, I was able to solve that issue by setting `location=(req.url)` from the server side configured static router. Going through this example I got the bigger picture I was missing.
https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/server-side-rendering-in-react-redux-ab0af31c9c4b